# Can a proxy server manipulate packets?

Tags: vpn, proxy

Can a proxy server inject malware by manipulating the packets sent through it and inject ,malware into my PCs memory that way?
I know that it could sniff my passwords.
What if i use a proxy server to connect to my VPN using the software overlay provided my VPN.
Will the packages be encrypted for the proxy or not?

Comment: Yes, packets are manipulated. No, it is very hard to inspect or change them if VPN encryption is properly configured.

Answer (score 1):

That's more than one question! Let's break it up.

> Can a proxy server inject malware by manipulating the packets sent
>   through it

Yes. As long the traffic is going unencrypted through the proxy, the proxy can manipulate the packages to do anything with it, like add malware, etc.

> and inject ,malware into my PCs memory that way? I know that it could
>   sniff my passwords.

What it *can* do is to inject a payload to your traffic, which exploits vulnerabilities of your system. By itself it is not able to access your memory, only "by proxy" (pun!) of an other exploit, which is served by the proxy (instead of by the serving (web)site).

> What if i use a proxy server to connect to my VPN using the software
>   overlay provided my VPN. Will the packages be encrypted for the proxy
>   or not?

Any traffic that goes encrypted (https/tls, vpn, ssh, etc.) through the proxy is *not* accessible by the proxy (assumed that the security protocols or properly implemented). In the postal service analogy: only the envelope is readable but not the content of the letter.

Comment: But be aware that, just like the envelope, you need to be sure that it's unopened and actually send by the person you think. That's why it's important to check the certificates, if you don't you can't be sure who you're communicating with. Also, it doesn't have to be a proxy, any system on the route between you and the other party, mostly routers, could do the same.